# Android using counter result to set visibility of ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, visibility, counter

I have a counter and I want to have the result from this counter dictate the visibility of an `ImageView`:

```
ImageView image_A_wrong = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage_a_wrong);
```

The ImageView's XML:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/small_wrong"
     android:id="@+id/IVimage_a_wrong" 
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
     android:padding="0dp"
     android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

I've tried a couple of things..here is some pseudo code of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (score == 0 ){
        image_A_wrong.getVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(score == 1){
        image_A_wrong.getVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
    }
}
```

I've looked around here, on tuts and on Adroid's Dev pag but cant seem to find / understand a solution applicable to my needs...thnx

Comment: is the `getVsibility` call supposed to be `setVisibility` ? Also how are you calling `setVisible`? With a true or a false? Does the counter change the `score` object? You need to post a lot more code I think...

Comment: yeah you are right, its supposed to be setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I thought the `true` `false`(if visible or not) was handled with (View.VISIBLE) since its `android:visibility="invisible"` on the XML. The `score` object is just a score that reflects/shows an int passed from another activity counter via a bundle...thnx

Answer (score 1):

You should use setVisibility() method rather than getVisibility():

```
    imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Yea you are right thnx..It is `imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` I just dont know what the method I should use for either a `swtich and case` or an `if` statement that checks the counter's result and depending on that result, makes a bitmap/drawable Visible or Invisible. I could assign an onClickLister to a button that checks the counter result. But I rather it be "checked" / ran once the activity starts..thnx

Answer (score 0):

So [View#VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) flags it as visible and [View#INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) flags it as not visible and [View#GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) hides the View altogether. 
This is what you need to do with your code:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (score == 0 ){
        //Hide the view
        image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if(score == 1){
        //Show the view
        image_A_wrong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
    }
}
```

I would recommend reading the [View#setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) documentation to get a better idea.

EDIT: Also I have no idea where View#setVisible(boolean) comes from that you are showing in your code above. Thats not a function in `View` that I know of...